# Why is this code throwing an out of memory exception?

Tags: haskell, sparse-matrix

I decided to dig up a Haskell project I started a few months ago. It's the beginning of a sparse matrix library. Can anyone see anything obvious about this code that would cause it to throw an out of memory exception for a medium sized matrix (2500 x 2500 doubles)? I understand that normally it's best to post complete build able code, I can post more if needed. The code below converts a SparseMatrix type (an IntMap (IntMap Double) ) into a more efficient SkyLine representation using unboxed vectors. This works fine for smaller matrices. I thought it might be related to the use of foldl vs. foldr, so I switched them but it didn't seem to make a difference. Is this a "space leak"? Thanks.

Edit: After looking at this a little more,I'm thinking the problem is the Vector Append. This must be creating a new Vector each time. I noticed I got a down vote, maybe if I solve the problem and post the answer I can regain some cred?

```
import Math.LinearAlgebra.Sparse hiding (mulMV,dot)
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

type IdxM = (Int,Int)

data SKYSpM = SKYSpM {val   :: V.Vector Double                   
                     ,rcIdx :: V.Vector (Int, Int)           
                     ,dims  :: IdxM
                     }deriving(Show)

skySpM :: Int -> SKYSpM
skySpM i = SKYSpM (V.empty::V.Vector Double) (V.empty::V.Vector (Int,Int)) (i,i)


toSKY :: SparseMatrix Double -> SKYSpM
toSKY m = SKYSpM v' (V.snoc idxs' $ V.last idxs') d' 
  where (SKYSpM v' idxs' d')  = foldl f (skySpM $ height m) [1..(height m)]
        f (SKYSpM v idxs d) i = SKYSpM (v V.++ v') (V.snoc idxs (V.length v,jmin-1)) d
          where v' = foldl (\acc x -> V.snoc acc (r ! x)) V.empty [jmin..jmax]
                (jmin,_) = (IM.findMin $ vec r) 
                (jmax,_) = (IM.findMax $ vec r) 
                r        = row m i
```

Comment: Have you tried using foldl', the strict variant of foldl?

Comment: In addition to what Rhymoid said, consider making the fields of your `SKYSpM` type strict if you don't make use of the laziness anywhere, otherwise using `foldl'` could leave of the fields of the accumulator unevaluated.

Comment: Yes, I tried both these suggestions. Now I'm getting a "Segmentation fault / access violation in generated code" error. I've never seen this error in Haskell before.